# GetCustomAttribute() returns null for AssemblyVersionAttribute

Tags: .net, null, assemblyversionattribute

I'm adding an About dialog to my .NET application and I'm querying the assembly's attributes for information to display. When I attempt to retrieve my assembly's [`AssemblyVersionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) using [`GetCustomAttribute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattribute.aspx) it returns `null`:

```
// Works fine
AssemblyTitleAttribute title
    = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
        someAssembly, typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute));

// Gets null
AssemblyVersionAttribute version
    = (AssemblyVersionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
        someAssembly, typeof(AssemblyVersionAttribute));
```

My `AssemblyInfo.cs` seems fine. I have these attributes defined:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Some Application")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

What's the deal? I do have a workaround, but I would like to know why the above code doesn't work.

```
// Work-around
string version = someAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: If you're in WinForms, you can just use `Application.ProductVersion`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `AssemblyVersionAttribute` is not added to the assembly, but is treated in a "special" way by the compiler (i.e. it sets the version of the assembly)

You CAN get the `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute (i.e. this one is added to the assembly)

There are other attributes that show the same behavior: the `AssemblyCultureAttribute` and `AssemblyFlagsAttribute` are also used for setting assembly properties, and are not added to the assembly as custom attributes.

All of these attributes are listed under the **Assembly Identity Attributes** in the documentation. The documentation says this about these attributes:

> Three attributes, together with a strong name (if applicable), determine the identity of an assembly: name, version, and culture.

Comment: It seems that it is treated differently because it is actually considered a "pseudo custom attribute," not a regular custom attribute.

Answer (score 9):

Your example is not a work-around. It's exactly what the MSDN documentation states you should do, which leads me to believe that code is by-design.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx

> To get the name [sic] of an assembly you have loaded, call `GetName` on the assembly to get an `AssemblyName`, and then get the `Version` property. To get the name of an assembly you have not loaded, call `GetAssemblyName` from your client application to check the assembly version that your application uses.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why it behaves this way.  Instead of going after the AssemblyVersionAttribute we do this:

```
Version AssemblyVersion = someAssembly.GetName().Version;
```

For AssemblyFileVersion we use:

```
Version fileVersion = new Version("0.0.0.0");
AssemblyFileVersionAttribute[] fileVersionAttributes = (AssemblyFileVersionAttribute[])assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), true);
if (fileVersionAttributes != null && fileVersionAttributes.Length > 0) {
    fileVersion = new Version(fileVersionAttributes[0].Version);
}
```