# How to get Assembly Version (not File Version) for another EXE?

Tags: c#, .net

You can use the following to get the File Version:

```
FileVersionInfo versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("filename.exe");
```

But how can you get the Assembly Version for a specific EXE file?

Comment: Take a look at this link and see if it answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187495/how-to-read-assembly-attributes

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From this blog article [How to get assembly version without loading it](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2008/09/05/how-to-get-assembly-version-without-loading-it.aspx):

```
AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("filename.exe").Version
```

This avoids having to load the assembly in its entirity.

Comment: This allows to delete the assembly after that check, even if the application is still running. Great!