# Getting Assembly Version from AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, assemblyinfo

We have an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in our Web Application but we do have other projects in the same solution. They are mostly class libraries. I am told to display Assembly Version from `AssemblyInfo.cs` on our UI. I've found the following solution in SO from [C# AssemblyFileVersion usage within a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699580/c-sharp-assemblyfileversion-usage-within-a-program)

```
using System.Reflection;
Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

or

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

FileVersionInfo fv = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo
                               (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Console.WriteLine("AssemblyVersion : {0}", 
         Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());

Console.WriteLine ("AssemblyFileVersion : {0}" , 
         fv.FileVersion.ToString ());
```

But this confuses me little bit. It says `GetExecutingAssembly()` and what if it is running on another assembly from other class libraries? Will those codes fetch from `AssemblyInfo.cs` file that is residing in the Web Project all the time? (which is what I want)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724546/how-to-get-assembly-version-not-file-version-for-another-exe This question talks about getying version of any assembly.

Comment: Thanks for but I don't need any assembly's instead I want from `AssemblyInfo.cs` and I want to make sure it is coming from there.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As the documentation states, `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` gets the assembly that the calling code was compiled inside of.

If you want to be more explicit (and faster), you can write `typeof(SomeType).Assembly`, where `SomeType` is any type in the project you're looking for.

Comment: Then can you show me how to get Assembly Version info from `AssemblyInfo.cs`of the Web Application all the time? I just want to ensure that the field I need is coming from there.

Comment: @Tarik: Use any type from that project.

Comment: This answer led me to the following (VB) code: `New ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())`

Comment: Very simple. Thanks. typeof(SomeType).Assembly

Comment: @SLaks - You led me there and I gave you the upvote.  However, the answer could be worded better to give it to the viewer without having to do extra work to find the answer.
For me the answer was:  


    System.Reflection.Assembly theAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

 

   // and the actual Version value is:
 
   var AssemblyVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

Answer (score -4):

if you want read file then you can do this.

```
string path = @"d:\AssemblyInfo.cs";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Open the file to read from.
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            var versionInfoLines = readText.Where(t => t.Contains("[assembly: AssemblyVersion"));
            foreach (string item in versionInfoLines)
            {
                string version = item.Substring(item.IndexOf('(') + 2, item.LastIndexOf(')') - item.IndexOf('(') - 3);          
                Console.WriteLine(version);
            }

        }
```

Output

```
1.0.0.0
```

Comment: This gets the version from the source file, yes - but the source code file won't be available when a program is running, say, on a customer's computer.

Comment: nobody is making you point at a source file.  You could reference a dll or html page.