# Increasing a version between a XML Tag

Tags: c#

I have made a application to update my other applications. I am using autoupdater.net library to handle the updates. My question is how can I get the version of one application from another?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
    <version>1.0.1.0</version> // I would like to update this with the assembly version of another application
    <url></url>
    <changelog></changelog>
    <mandatory mode="2">true</mandatory>
</item>
```

What this application does is deletes the current zip, zips up the release folder and then the last step would be updating this xml document with the new version number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify XML existing content in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551307/modify-xml-existing-content-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HereticMonkey that helps with the edit but then I need to be able to get the version number of the other assembly to write to the note.

Comment: Doing some research on your own would be nice... [Getting the Version of my C# app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36351866/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey reading the question would be nice... Not trying to get the version number of the application updater application just the version of the application it is updating...

Comment: Considering your question includes no code, and doesn't reference what application is getting what version where. This was a tough one. I had to add "another" to the search phrase "how to get the version of another assembly": [How to get Assembly Version (not File Version) for another EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2724546/215552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"filepath");

var versionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("item/version");
versionNode.InnerText = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
doc.Save(@"filepath");
```

You can also load the xml from a string directly if you don't have a file on your disk. Also this gets the version string of the executing assembly. Replace this with the version number if needed.

Comment: Very close, but I am trying to get the assembly version of a entirely different assembly

Comment: You can also use Assembly.GetAssembly(someTypeInTargetAssembly) to get another assembly version

Comment: Or if you need to get the version of an assembly without even loading it, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187999/how-do-i-get-the-version-of-an-assembly-without-loading-it

Comment: I tested it with the xml you provided, works for me. To navigate through the nodes with SelectSingleNode, you can just use xpath syntax. Here's a list of available options: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp