# Equivalent of C# Application.ProductName in Mono

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm looking for a way to get the equivalent of C# Application.ProductName in Mono.
Like project name of assembly name.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.ProductName` in fact reads the `AssemblyProductAttribute`, as revealed in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.productname.aspx

Thus, you can simply use the equivalent code to achieve the same effect, as demonstrated in

[How to read assembly attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187495/how-to-read-assembly-attributes)