# Programmatically (using C#) determine current Visual Studio build configuration

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013

My Visual Studio 2013 C# app needs to programmatically determine if another Visual Studio solution has been saved in "build mode" or "release mode". Is there an API for accomplishing this?

Alternatively, I was thinking of using the MSBuild API to build the solution and then check to see if the app has debug symbols. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: You could declare a symbol within a "#if DEBUG" then inspect that symbol via reflection.

Comment: @MobyDisk: That's a pretty cool idea, but this has to work across the entire company for all samples that we ship. Therefore, I'm hoping for a solution that won't require all sample writers to update their code for my app to function.

Answer (score 2):

**Debug**, **Release** or any other custom configuration are just names, anyone can make one to look like the other one in *Advanced Build Settings* of *Project Properties* or by tweaking properties in the `.csproj` directly. Those flags will dictate how you identify a "debug" assembly and how much of "debug" debug really means. That said, the difference in output for **default** combination of properties is in `Debuggable` assembly attribute, both default configurations have it and you can see it for yourself using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

**Debug**

```
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default
 | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations
 | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints
 | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
```

**Release**

```
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
```

On how to read this `Debuggable` attribute value -- see @MobyDisk answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you build an assembly in debug mode, the compiler adds the [assembly: DebuggableAttribute] automatically.  You can use reflection to see if that attribute is present on the assembly.  Take a look here for details on how to read attributes from an assembly: [How to read assembly attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187495/how-to-read-assembly-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently solving the same problem using Web.config:

My Web.config (as default this will be equivalent to Web.Debug.config and Web.Development.config) file contains (using your naming above):

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="mode" value="build"/>
    <add key="anotherKey" value="another value"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

My Web.Test.config and Web.Release.config files contain:

```
 <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="mode" value="release" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can access the 'mode' using:

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mode");
```

[you don't have to use 'mode' for the key, as long as you are consistent]