# How can I tell which reference is adding a permission in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In my final AndroidManifest, found under `Droid\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml`, I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, my main project does not have those permissions listed.  In fact, the word "Internet" doesn't appear anywhere in my entire solution!

According to [this forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56809/android-manifest-permissions-dont-match-the-ones-asked-during-install),

> Any library can set permissions that it needs, which automatically get added during compilation

But I have no idea how to tell which library is adding them!  So **how can I figure out which library is adding permissions to my app?**

Comment: Wen you compile in Debug conf, storage and internetbare automatically added. Can make a release build and see if they arevstill there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the Manifest you postet shows that you are compiling in *Debug Configuration*.

In Debug mode, `Internet` and `Storage` are automatically added, as [documented here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/permissions/) (last paragraph).

Try compiling a Release Build and they should be gone.

---

The additional permissions are added by putting an [`UsesPermissionAttribute`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.UsesPermissionAttribute/) into the `AssemblyInfos.cs`.

You can read those using reflection, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187495/how-to-read-assembly-attributes).

*I don't know how to see those attributes in VS just from the compiled assembly. If someone gives a hint, I'll add it here.*

Comment: For further reference, this is specifically in the `ManifestDocument.cs` code of `xamarin-android`: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/a8f7db057334be3124cabccd2cb2fd7dcf45f458/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Utilities/ManifestDocument.cs#L298-L302

Comment: That was it, thanks!  But, for future googlers who find this question, do you know the answer to the title-question?

Comment: Using reflection, by looking for the permission. I updated the answer.